# Mysql how to avoid repeating myself

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design, data-modeling, dry

I have a table students with the following fields.

```
Id,FirstName,SecondName,Photo,Student_ID
```

I also have a table called class_of_2011 with the fields

```
Id,FirstName,SecondName,Photo,Student_ID,Subjects
```

I want to select some specific students from table students and have them in table class_of_2011,but I already have the names in table students.I am thinking the only way to do this is to copy the names i want to the table class_of_2011,but since there will be a class of 2012 and beyond,I feel like I will be simply copying data from one table to the other.

Is repeating myself inevitable in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Students Table**
Id,FirstName,SecondName,Photo,Student_ID

**Subjects Table**
Id,Subject

**Student_Subjects Table**
Id,Student_Id,Subject_Id,Year

You may then assign a student multiple subjects, for multiple years.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this could be normalized easily. Why not have your `class_of_` tables simply have a foreign key to the `student` table's `id` column?

`StudentId,Subjects`

In this way, one student record could be associated with several classes, in case someone is on the 5-year plan.

I'm assuming that the `Student_ID` field in the `Students` table is their id number or something, and not the primary key of that table.

Comment: +1 For mentioning the [Five-Year Plan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-Year_Plans_for_the_National_Economy_of_the_Soviet_Union). Comrade. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `class_of_2011` table should contain the primary key of the `students` table and none of the other "repeated" data. All of the other columns you're interested in can then be obtained by joining the two columns together in a query.

Answer (score 1):

I would restructure the data if possible...  Something like....

```
Student Table
ID, Name, Address, other common specific to student

GraduatingClass Table
YearGraduate, StudentID

Enrollment Table
StudentID, ClassID, SemesterID
```